# Compressing traffic is very slow in .net core 2 service fabric web app

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-service-fabric

In my service fabric web service I am bundling up various js libraries which means my biggest file is now approximately 7MB in size and takes a few seconds to download. In order to try and improve the performance of the download I added response compression (UseResponseCompression). Unfortunately this has had the effect of significantly increasing the overall download time, but did manage to reduce the size of file to approximately 2MB.

Obviously this is not desirable, I'm using HttpSys for the web server. Is there anything else I can do to improve the size/download speed here?

Comment: Normally when I come across a rather large bundle, it means the bundler isn't configured optimally. What are you using to bundle your js?

Comment: I'm just using Gulp to concatenate the files and with a gulp-uglify to minify, just the default configuration though.

Comment: Can you add your Gulp script to your question? It may provide some valuable insight.